# In Java, when I pass an array to a recursive method, I get an error.

Tags: java, recursion, methods

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TreeOperations {
public  static int minDepthBT(int[] a, int i )
{
 if((i<1)|| (i<a.length))
     return 0;
 int x = minDepthBT(a[2*i],(2*i));
 int y = minDepthBT(a[2*i+1],(2*i +1));
 if(y==0) return y+1;
 else if(x==0) return x+1;   
 return Math.min(x,y);
}


public static void main(String[] akjhk) throws IOException
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
  int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
  int a[] = new int[n];
  String s[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      a[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
  }
  int depth = minDepthBT(a,1);
  out.println(depth);
  }
}
```

In the above code the error is shown in two pics here [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ALt.png) and [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwokG.png).

When I use an iterative method for example :

```
  int Sum(int a[])
   {
     int sum =0;
     for(int i=0;i<a,length;i++) sum += a[i];
     return sum;
   }
```

no error is received. What does happen in case of recursive methods?

Comment: Please please please: do not use single character names for variables (if at all: as counters in for loops). The 1 second you save on typing ... you spent later on when asking yourself "what as that thing supposed to mean again" (well, you save 1 second on typing, but you will spend minutes on thinking, guaranteed!)

Comment: cuz this a[2*i]  will resolve to an int not to an array

Comment: thank you :) @GhostCat .

Comment: And hint no. 2: dont put error messages up as links. Error messages contain **text**, and this text ... you can copy here. And seriously: you read that text first. As it normally tells you **exactly** what you did wrong in your program!

Comment: @PavneetSingh but why  is it happening so? answer please :) .

Comment: You already got your a correct answer; so just go forward and accept that, before people start downvoting you for this question ;-)

Comment: @AmirHasan minDepthBT need first input as array, now use my first comment  and think about this  minDepthBT(a[2*i],(2*i));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
int x = minDepthBT(a[2*i],(2*i));
```

for example.

Your method is declared to have two parameters: an array of int, and an int.

Here, you are calling the method ... using **two** int values.

Long story short: when calling your method recursively, then you have to provide exactly those parameters that are expected; in your case: you probably want to simply call with `(a, 2*i)`.

EDIT:

Or, you would have to do something like:

```
int arrayForRecursiveCall[] = new int[whatever length];
... then you put some values in that array and then
minDepthBT(arrayForRecursiveCall, 2*i);
```

As said - the core thing is: you have to pass an **array** as first argument. A single int cant work!

Comment: I am understanding that the recursive call  is expecting an array means an address of some position.   I want to pass the  address of a[ 2*i ].  I am still not getting  how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As your IDE noticed: The method minDepthBT(int[], int) in not applicable for the arguments (int, int). In other words you are trying to pass some int value **AS AN ARRAY** while it is an element of the array.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
//array - this is how we pass array as argument
//array[1] - this how we pass array's element as argument

minDepthBT(array[1], someInteger); // this is what you are doing
minDepthBT(array, someInteger);    // this is what you should do
```